# I need to switch an item out for another

Tags: python, list, loops, python-2.7

I'm having trouble changing a specific item in a sublist and it would be nice to know how
this is what ive come up with so far:

```
    board = [123,[4, 5, 6]]
    for item in board:
        item[0] = "X"
```

i would like to know how i could the output of:

```
    input: print board
    output: [123,['X', 5, 6]]
```

Comment: And why is `board[1][0] = 'X'` not sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

You can repeatedly subscript to access the elements of nested lists.

```
board[1][0] = 'X'
```

Also in Python, it's generally bad practice to have heterogenous lists. It's much more Pythonic to keep lists homogenous (all elements of the list should have the same basic type).